# How do I take automatically bracketed exposures with the Canon XSi?

Tags: canon, exposure, canon-450d, bracketing

I'm trying to help someone with a Canon XSi. I'm not used to the Canons that use menus (rather than buttons on the body).

Does anyone know how to set up the Canon XSi to take a bracketed exposure of 3 photos? -1, 0, and +1?

Comment: This is one of the things that seems to be just a little more difficult than it should be on a Canon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Canon 450D/XSi has the ability to automatically bracket exposures +/- 3.0 EV, in 0.5 or 0.3 EV increments.  To get to the AEB menu you have to have another thing setup correctly.  It is displayed only in the **P, TV, Av, M or A-DEP modes**, not in any of the 'Basic Zone' modes (such as full Auto or the Scene modes). Once you have that setup, **hit the Menu button** on the back and scroll over right to the **second option in the menu**, and you will see the first option is "AEB".  Select that and you can **expand the selection** using the right and left arrows up to a full +/- 3 depending on what you would like.  In your particular case you would expand it to -1,0,and +1 to get the desired effect you asked for.

At this point when you start shooting images it will take a series of three images for the bracketing.  It is usually a benefit to put the camera into a continuous shooting mode for faster shots at this point, but that is a preference.

The website dpreview does have images of the menu if you would like a visual of that screen [here](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canoneos450d/page11.asp).

Comment: Nice description in your answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

"AEB" at the top of the second photo-options menu.

Comment: Here's a video tutorial. Fast forward to 1:50 to skip the into: http://scanonxsi.blogspot.com/2009/01/canon-xsi-auto-exposure-bracketing.html